# nginx rewrite subfolder in url not working

Tags: nginx

i have a site which was previously an apache but because of some circumstances i have to move to a vps and use nginx instead. and im pretty much a noob in nginx

my folder structure is

root/pages/[all of my page files including index]

i want to remove pages folder in the url,

so from

```
1. mydomain.net/pages/index.php
2. mydomain.net/pages/subpage.php
```

to

```
1. mydomain.net
 2. mydomain.net/subpage
```

in apache i use:

```
RewriteEngine On

#remove php file extension-e.g. https://example.com/file.php will become https://example.com/file 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L] 

#remove folder name on link e.g. https://example.com/pages/file.php will become https://example.com/file.php 
RewriteRule ^$ pages/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pages/$1 [NC,L]
```

and now i tried to change it to nginx with these code

```
server {


        root /var/www/html;
        index pages/index.php;
        server_name mydomain.net www.mydomain.net;

        # to run php
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        }

        #deny htaccess
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }                                                                                                                        
        
        # remove .php extension in url
        location @extensionless-php {
            rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
        } 
        
        # supposed to remove pages folder in url 
        location /pages
        {   
            rewrite ^/pages(/.*)$ $1 last;
        }  
}
```

*mydomain.net* works fine

but somehow i got 404 error in *mydomain/subpage*

Comment: Just set `root` to `root /var/www/html/pages;` there is no need to rewrite anything.

Comment: i tried but now my css and javascript and images are not working.. cuz they are in a folder outside the pages folder..

Comment: Is only your PHP files in the pages folder? You could put the `root /var/www/html/pages;` statement inside the `location ~ \.php$` block.